# Run cron job every 10 minutes, from 4:40 to 0:15

Tags: cron

I need to run a cron job every 10 minutes, only between 4:40 and 0:15. I've managed to schedule the cron job to run from 4 to 0 o'clock, but can't figure out how to schedule it further. This is what I came out with: `*/10   4-23,0  *   *   * script`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sometimes you just have to break out the ugly, and duplicate entries to get selection logic like that. It should work and be pretty apparent with what it's doing without uber cron-fu knowledge.

```
40,50 4 * * * script
*/10 5-23 * * * script
0,10 0 * * * script
```

Oh, and a helpful site for generating these: http://www.openjs.com/scripts/jslibrary/demos/crontab.php

Comment: I was wondering about splitting the cron into 3, but thought there is a more elegant way of doing it. Anyway, will go for it, thank you!